# YouTube API Modal Popup not playing on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I'm stumped on this one, but I'm also not strong in JS. I can get everything to open as it should, but I just can't the video to play on a button click. Below is my code

before /head

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
  var player;
   function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {player = new YT.Player('my-video');}
</script>
```

button and modal

```
<a href="#" id="playVideoBtn" data-ix="fade-in-and-out" class="w-inline-block play-wrapper" ><img width="45" height="45" src="images/play-button-big.png">

<iframe id="my-video" style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%; border:0px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7LTwhhs8GCo?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

the js before /body

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#playVideoBtn').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.modal-background.video').fadeIn();
      player.playVideo();
    });
    $('#close-video').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.modal-background.video').fadeOut();
      player.stopVideo();
    });
    $('.modal-background-link').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.modal-background.video').fadeOut();
      player.stopVideo();
    });
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the event get fired, and is player set or is it undefined?

Comment: Put a console.log(player) in playVideoBtn click event